# Bootstrap 3 How to Assign unique gutter widths to Specific row's?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, row, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 to build my personal website and have been searching for a way to do the following:

I would like to assign unique gutter widths to specific rows in my layout.

The rest of the website will make use of the underlying gutter width.
Is it possible? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in Advance / Trev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Add a unique CSS class, say `my-personalized-row` to the row you want to edit. Then in your CSS, add a section for this as following:

```
.my-personalized-row {
    margin-bottom: 5px !important; //If you want 5px of gutter width.
}
```

Now, whatever you put between the two braces will apply only to this row and the rest of the site will use the underlying gutter width.

**UPDATE:**

I have added the style rule you would want to use to reduce the gutter width for a specific row to 5px. The `!important` is to ensure that specificity rules will not interfere with your declaration. Note that it is not mandatory to use `!important` since Bootstrap declares styles with a single class as well.

Comment: Hi there Chandranshu and thanks for you help. I have managed to add the my-personalised-row into the HTML but still not sure Hows to target the gutter width in CSS.. Any ideas as to how the CSS would look?

Comment: Thanks Chandranshu, appreciate the guidance. All looks good over here.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrond but it seems this is not the correct answer. `margin-bottom` has nothing related to changing the gutter width.

Comment: @RenatoCarvalho - I understand the confusion created by the use of the word 'gutter' which is generally understood to be the space between the columns. But the question is about "gutter widths of rows". Technically the space between two rows is also gutter though CSS folks don't call it so.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to change the spacing between columns (gutter) is to use CSS to override the default padding (15px)..

```
.row .col:not(:first-child),.row .col:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right:5px;
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/94849

Comment: This one worked for me. But I had also to change the 'margin-left' and the 'margin-right' of my customized row.